# List of deleting rows in datagridview

Tags: c#, events, datagridview

I got a DataGridView which just allows user to delete rows (with no direct editing or adding on DataGridView). I will update my database information whenever user deletes rows on DataGridView (there is no binding among DB and gridview).

I have no problem to have deleting row when user is deleting only one row using DeletingRow event like below:

```
private void dataGridView1_UserDeletingRow(object sender, DataGridViewRowCancelEventArgs e)
{
    DataGridViewRow row = e.Row;     //only single row
}
```

However i could not capture list of *all* rows when user selects *multiple* rows and delete them.
Above event only called once for first row only. In order to handle this case i did set `dataGridView1.MultiSelect = false;` however this is a workaround!
 So how can i have list of all selected rows which user is deleting, currently?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All selected rows will be available at `dataGridView1.SelectedRows`
so you can do something like:

```
    void dataGridView1_UserDeletingRow(object sender, DataGridViewRowCancelEventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in this.dataGridView1.SelectedRows)
        {
            this.HandleRowDeletion(row);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `dataGridView1.SelectedRows` to get a collection (`DataGridViewRowCollection` type) that contains all the rows selected. Same works for columns (`dataGridView1.SelectedColumns`) and cells (`dataGridView1.SelectedCells`).

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.selectedrows.aspx